# Como alterar a estrutura de gráficos em ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Utilizei a seguinte linha de comando do `ggplot2` em R para gerar o gráfico em anexo:

```
g1 <- ggplot(count, aes(x=cluster, y=Reads)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ Spp) 

ggplot(count, aes(x=cluster, y=Reads, fill=Spp, col=Spp)) + 
  geom_point(shape=1)
```

Esse gráfico diz respeito a quantidade de sequências de DNA em cada cluster de sequencias similares de duas espécies (Ca e Cp). Os clusters localizados na faixa de 0 reads de uma espécie são clusters enriquecidos na outra espécie. Para tentar deixar isso mais visual gostaria de plotar o gráfico da espécie Ca (os resultados que estão na cor alaranjada) na região superior e manter o da espécie Cp na região inferior. Literalmente inverter o gráfico de Ca junto, inclusive, com uma escala de Y no outro oposto, também invertida. A ideia é fazer como no esquema, mas claro, com os dados dispersos e não em uma reta.

```
structure(list(cluster = 1:20, Spp = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = 
c("Ca", "Cp"), class = "factor"), Reads = c(10808L, 16118L, 7928L, 
4171L, 6525L, 2480L, 4151L, 7870L, 2508L, 2141L, 1318L, 6072L, 6459L, 
10270L, 2068L, 55L, 1108L, 2116L, 4219L, 3939L)), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso utilizando o pacote `ggplot2`?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode, por favor, **editar a pergunta** com a saída de `dput(count)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(count, 20))`?

Comment: Pronto. Editada.

Comment: Parece que a resposta está na pergunta. Tente imprimir o gráfico que você salvou em `g1`. `print(g1)`

Comment: @TomásBarcellos em g1 eu tenho o gráfico de apenas uma das espécies. Com facet eu ploto as duas espécies em gráficos separados e com o último comando eu ploto as duas espécies no mesmo gráfico, que é o em anexo.

Comment: Não entendi bem o que você precisa. Pode tentar explicar de outra forma na pergunta?

Comment: @TomásBarcellos Fiz um esquema da ideia e acho que pode ter ficado mais claro, da uma olhada ae.

Comment: Há um problema com os dados, só têm `Spp = "Cp"` não há linhas com `Spp = "Ca"`. Talvez `dput(head(count, 40))`? Mas verifique antes os dados, por favor.

Comment: Outra coisa. O que o ggplot2 faz é visualizar dados. Isso significa que seus dados tem que estar prontos para serem visualizados ou então, você terá que transformá-los.

Comment: E no seu caso, a julgar pela imagem do segundo gráfico, é como se os dois grupos se comportassem como a curva azul do primeiro gráfico.

Comment: Só tem a ```Spp = Cp``` pois utilizei a função ```facet_grid(. ~ Spp) ```. A distribuição dos dados das duas espécies é similar mesmo. Era de se esperar esse padrão. E valeu @RuiBarradas a sua solução deu exatamente o resultado que queria.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A seguinte solução utiliza a função `sec_axis` com uma transformação idêntica à da `geom_point` que inverte os valores de `Spp = "Ca"`.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = subset(count, Spp = "Cp"),
             mapping = aes(cluster, Reads), color = "red") +
  geom_point(data = subset(count, Spp = "Ca"),
             mapping = aes(cluster, max(Reads) - Reads), color = "blue") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ max(.) - ., name = derive())) +
  labs(x = "Cluster", y = "Spp")
```